# Cannot understand the ordering of child process creation

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have just started with `node` and in this program, I am creating 3 child processes, but receiving the return signals in a weird order.

**parent.js**

```
var child_process = require("child_process");

for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    var child = child_process.exec("node child.js "+i,function(err,stdout){
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            console.log(stdout);
    });
};
```

**child.js**

```
var num = process.argv[2];
console.log("Child process "+num+" started.");
process.on('exit',function(){
    console.log("Process "+num+" ended.");
});
```

**Output:**

```
Child process 2 started.
Process 2 ended.

Child process 0 started.
Process 0 ended.

Child process 1 started.
Process 1 ended.
```

I think it might be a race condition, but I get the exact output every time. I am really not sure about the reason behind this.

(Ubuntu 14.04, Node 5.5)

Comment: Sure, creating processes is an asynchronous process and the OS can start/stop them in any order it chooses. This is to be expected.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224226/async-nodejs-execution-order

Comment: @phenxd Thanks, I didn't know that async tasks had a random order to them. Closing.